# Is Windows safe from BadUSB/Rubber Ducky on lock screen?

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, malware, lock-screen

If there’s computer with the login screen on, will plugging BadUSB/Rubber Ducky infect PC? Or is it only possible when you log in to Windows?

Answer (score 2):

It only replicates a human typing on a keyboard so unless the BadUSB has knowledge about user / pass combination it is safe.